# Proper C++ indentation in Emacs: classes and structs

Tags: c++, emacs, indentation

I have been looking at other answers, e.g. [emacs: different indentation for class and struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715689/emacs-different-indentation-for-class-and-struct), and none of the suggested answers seem to work for me. This is my header file:

```cpp
// my_header
namespace foo
{
    template<typename T>
    class ResizablePoolAllocator
    {
        static_assert(sizeof(T) >= sizeof(void*));  // 'brace-list-intro
    public:
    inline T* Alloc() { return (T*)_alloc(); }      // 'brace-list-entry
    inline void Free(T* ptr) { _free(ptr); }        // 'brace-list-entry

    private:
    void* _alloc();                                 // 'brace-list-entry
    void _free(void* ptr);                          // 'brace-list-entry
    };
}
```

The indentation should be indented by `'tab-width` at the function declarations following the two labels `public` and `private`. This is the relevant section of the init file:

```lisp
(defun my-cpp-common-mode-hook ()
  (c-set-offset 'substatement-open 0)
  (c-set-offset 'inline-open 0)
  (c-set-offset 'comment-intro 0)
  (c-set-offset 'defun-block-intro 'tab-width)
  (c-set-offset 'statement-block-intro 'tab-width)
  (c-set-offset 'substatement 'tab-width)
  (c-set-offset 'topmost-intro 0)
  (c-set-offset 'statement-cont 'tab-width)
  (c-set-offset 'func-decl-cont 0)
  (c-set-offset 'brace-list-open 0)
  (c-set-offset 'brace-list-intro 'tab-width)
  (c-set-offset 'brace-list-entry 0)
  ;; EXPERIMENTAL:
  ;;(c-set-offset 'arglist-intro 'c-lineup-arglist-intro-after-paren)
  (c-set-offset 'arglist-intro 'tab-width)
  )

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (setq indent-tabs-mode t)
        (setq tab-width 4)
        (setq c-basic-offset 4)
        (highlight-doxygen-mode t)
        )
      )
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my-cpp-common-mode-hook)
```

Unfortunately, I can't just insert `(c-set-offset 'brace-list-entry 'tab-width)`, as that would recursively extra-indent all lines that have this tag.

I think I need something like this:

```
;; PSEUDOCODE
(setq 'brace-list-entry (if (= previous-line brace-list_entry) 0 'tab-width)
```

But I don't know how to accomplish this / if it is even possible with `"GNU Emacs 27.1"`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've got a setup that I tinkered together years ago and haven't really touched since. I turned it loose on your sample and this is the result:

```
namespace foo
{
    template<typename T>
      class ResizablePoolAllocator
    {
        static_assert(sizeof(T) >= sizeof(void*));  // 'brace-list-intro
    public:
        inline T* Alloc() { return (T*)_alloc(); }      // 'brace-list-entry
        inline void Free(T* ptr) { _free(ptr); }        // 'brace-list-entry

    private:
        void* _alloc();                                 // 'brace-list-entry
        void _free(void* ptr);                          // 'brace-list-entry
    };
}
```

The full style machinery looks like this:

```
(defconst my-c-style
    '((c-recognize-knr-p          . nil)
      (c-tab-always-indent        . t)
      (c-basic-offset             . 4)
      (c-comment-only-line-offset . 0)
      (c-hanging-braces-alist     . ((block-close . c-snug-do-while)
                                     (brace-entry-open)
                                     (brace-list-close)
                                     (brace-list-open after)
                                     (brace-list-intro)
                                     (class-open after)
                                     (class-close before)
                                     (extern-lang-open after)
                                     (inexpr-class-open after)
                                     (inexpr-class-close before)
                                     (inline-open after)
                                     (inline-close before)
                                     (statement-cont)
                                     (substatement-open after)))
      (c-hanging-colons-alist     . ((member-init-intro before)
                                     (inher-intro)
                                     (case-label after)
                                     (label after)
                                     (access-label after)))
      (c-cleanup-list             . (scope-operator
                                     empty-defun-braces
                                     defun-close-semi))
      (c-offsets-alist            . ((access-label . -)
                                     (brace-list-close . 0)
                                     (brace-list-entry . 0)
                                     (brace-list-intro . +)
                                     (class-close . 0)
                                     (class-open . 0)
                                     (defun-block-intro . +)
                                     (defun-close . 0)
                                     (defun-open . 0)
                                     (inclass . +)
                                     (label . 0)
                                     (statement . 0)
                                     (statement-cont . *)
                                     (topmost-intro-cont . 0)
                                     (arglist-close . c-lineup-arglist)
                                     (block-open . 0)
                                     (case-label . +)
                                     (func-decl-cont . c-lineup-java-throws)
                                     (inexpr-class . 0)
                                     (inher-cont . c-lineup-java-inher)
                                     (inline-open . 0)
                                     (substatement-open . 0)
                                     (innamespace . 0)
                                     ))
      (c-echo-syntactic-information-p . t))
    "My C Programming Style")
;; Offset customizations not in my-c-style
(setq c-offsets-alist '((member-init-intro . ++)))
;; Customizations for all modes in CC Mode.
(defun my-c-mode-common-hook ()
  ;; add my personal style and set it for the current buffer
  (c-add-style "PERSONAL" my-c-style t)
  ;; other customizations
  (setq tab-width 4)
  ;; we like auto-newline and hungry-delete
  (c-toggle-auto-hungry-state 1)
  ;; keybindings for all supported languages.  We can put these in
  ;; c-mode-base-map because c-mode-map, c++-mode-map, objc-mode-map,
  ;; java-mode-map, idl-mode-map, and pike-mode-map inherit from it.
  (define-key c-mode-base-map "\C-m" 'newline-and-indent)
  (define-key c-mode-base-map "\M-a" 'backward-sexp)
  (define-key c-mode-base-map "\M-e" 'forward-sexp)
  )

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-c-mode-common-hook)
(setq c++-mode-hook
      '(lambda ()
         (font-lock-mode 1)
         ))
(setq java-mode-hook
      '(lambda ()
         (font-lock-mode 1)
         ))
```

Hope it helps.